# JavaScript - Increase font size of the selection in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on WYSIWYG editor which have button IncreaseFontSize (like in MS Office). I am trying to make this button works but without success. Everytime all selected elements have the same font size. Here is example:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>
         Some
         <span style="font-size: 20pt">Text</span>
         <span style="font-size: 32pt">Some</span>
         Text
    </p>
</div>
```

Below is part of my code

```
var html = $(rangy.getSelection().toHtml());
var firstValue = html.find('.fontSize').first().css('font-size').replace('px', '');

html.find('.fontSize').each(function () {
    $(this).css('font-size', parseInt(firstValue) + 1);
});
```

When I select all text and click this button all `spans` have the same font-size (for example 21pt, because my function brings only first `span` into consideration). So how can I do script which can increase font size of each element separately (using JavaScript or/and JQuery)? Thanks for help.

Comment: show us you js code.

Comment: ok. give me a secound

Comment: @moghya I have just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grabbing the value of the first span, storing it in `firstValue` and then setting the font size of ALL the spans to `firstValue + 1`. Since your first span is 20px, everything gets set to 21px

So if you are trying to increase each span by 1px when the button is clicked, you would do it this way:

```
html.find('.fontSize').each(function () {
    var oldValue = $(this).css('font-size');
    $(this).css('font-size', parseInt(oldValue) + 1);
});
```